# IE is not closing the window after form is submitted in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying the code below

```
var newForm = jQuery('<form>', {
                    'action': 'https://restore.com/download',
                    'method':'POST',
                    'target':'_blank',
                     'id':'newForm'
                });
                newForm.append("<input type='hidden' name='key' value='download'>")
                jQuery("#newForm").remove();
                jQuery("body").append(newForm)
                jQuery("#newForm").submit();
```

The above code is used to download some files and submit the form in a new window using

> target="_blank"

in Chrome and Firefox.

After the download starts, the new window closes.

But in IE, it does not close the new window.

I want to close the window.

Can anyone help me out.

Comment: Shouldn't need a new window if it is a forced download...or target an iframe instead

Comment: My advise is to use hidden iframe instead of new window and submit your form there. Should work.

Comment: no i cannot use iframe due to some restrictions

Answer (score 0):

Please try to make use of inline frames. I think then you will not face issue.

Comment: cannot use frames due to some restrictions

Comment: Can u try to use this:
javascript:top.close();

Comment: I can think of one thing window.close().
Can you try using window.close() for your new window.